# Send email to customer on order update via rest API

Tags: magento2, email, rest-api

I'm using **/rest/V1/orders POST WebService** to update an existing order. Is there any way to send an email to customer when the order is updated this way?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually really easy, I just used the **/rest/V1/orders/{orderId}/comments**

```
{
    "statusHistory": 
    {
        "is_customer_notified": 1,
        "parent_id":           your order Id,
        "status":              "Your order status",
        "comment":             "Your message",
        "is_visible_on_front": 1
    }
}
```